# How to download the logs stored in azure disk mapped to kubernetes persistent volume

Tags: azure-aks, azure-disk

I have mapped an azure disk to one of the kafka pods,I want to check the logs stored in the azure disk, is there any provision for this ?

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? Don't leave without any response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got sorted by doing ssh into the specific node placed under AKS cluster and checking into the mounted disk to that

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, I think you can ssh into the pods to check the logs stored in the disk. Actually, Azure disk is a VHD file, so you cannot check the files inside it when it is not in the attached state.

Comment: If I ssh into the pod, then primarily it will give me local logs of the pod, not of all time. May be I can now try attaching that disk to a VM and then check into, if AKS allows that

Comment: @TusharMahajan Yes, you can detach the disk when the pod finishes the life cycle. And then attached the disk to a VM.

Comment: @TusharMahajan I think the static disk is a good choice. Additional, if it solves your problem, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: @TusharMahajan Any more questions? And if it works for you please accept it as the answer.

Comment: This got sorted by doing ssh into the specific node placed under AKS cluster and checking into the mounted disk to that

Comment: @TusharMahajan So, does it solve your problem? Or you think it's not the answer you expected?

Comment: No Charles, your answer was not appropriate solution to this